Shell variable acts differently if I have fetched it using curl and sed
Shell variable acts differently if I have fetched it using curl and sed
I am trying to fetch the latest release version of a github repo using curl and then use it in a variable named HELLO:
HELLO=$(curl -I https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/latest|grep location:|grep -Eoh "tag\/.*"|sed 's/tag\/v//'|sed 's/[\r\n]//')

I am also storing the string "1.105.0" in a variable called HELLO2.
HELLO2="1.105.0"

Now both HELLO and HELLO contain a similarly formatted string:
$ echo $HELLO
1.105.0
$ echo $HELLO2
1.105.0

However, both variables act differently when I want to output them as part of a string:
$ echo v"$HELLO2"/
v1.105.0/
$ echo v"$HELLO"/ 
/1.105.0

I am expecting the latter command to output "v1.105.0/" but it outputs "/1.105.0"
I am using zsh on macOS:
$ echo $0
zsh


Don't trust echo. Use printf '%q\n' "$var" to see what a variable contains using printable characters. In this case, you have a literal carriage return in your data -- a character that sends the cursor to the left of the screen when printed.

Note that using sed to modify newlines is not well defined behavior; whether it works at all is implementation-dependent. Better to use either shell builtins or tr.

(the shell-builtin approach would look like HELLO=${HELLO//$'\r'/}, to use bash-extension syntax that I want to say zsh supports as well; btw, as general practice, stay away from all-caps variable names -- those are in the reserved space used for variables meaningful to POSIX-specified tools / OS components, whereas lowercase names are guaranteed not to have unintended effects on POSIX-defined tools -- that said, zsh is not POSIX-compliant, so you don't get the guarantee there as you would with bash/dash/ash/ksh/sh/etc)

How can you know, that your variables contain the same value? Since you are using zsh, you can use i.e. xxd <<<$HELLO to see what's in it.

@user1934428, ...mind, that'll add a trailing newline (in the process of writing the heredoc) rather than printing the exact contents of the variable.

(mind, all the above is assuming that zsh is what you're using to actually run your script, which is completely separate from $0 or $SHELL at an interactive prompt; the first line of your script is what determines the interpreter it uses -- if it starts with #!/bin/sh, for example, it'll run with sh rather than bash or zsh whenever invoked through an execve() call).

@CharlesDuffy: Yes, but since xxd always adds the newline, we know this and can conclude that the content is what is before the final newline. I just find it the most convenient way to see the hex content, not the aesthetically most pleasant one.

BTW, to quickly check which shell I'm running, I often enter a single ).  The resulting error message typically shows the shell name.
